# When to include headers for built-in types and operators?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, new-operator, initializer-list, typeinfo

When should one include headers for built-in types?

- `<new>` for `new` (seems for sophisticated overloadings it is really needed); it can be just used.
- (edit: wrong example (see answers)) `<typeinfo>` for `std::type_info`; it can be just acquired by using `typeid` operator
- (edit: wrong example (see answers)) `<initializer_list>` for `std::initizlizer_list`; it is just result of `auto l = {1, 2, 3};` or temporary in `for (int i : {1, 2, 3}) {}`
- `<cstddef>`/`<cstdio>`/`<cstring>`/`<ctime>` for `std::size_t`; it can be given as result of operator `sizeof val` or `sizeof(Type)`
- `<cstddef>` for `std::nullptr_t`; `decltype(nullptr)`
- `<cstddef>` for `std::ptrdiff_t`; `decltype(std::declval<int *>() - std::declval<int *>())`
- `<tuple>` for some functionality of structured bindings
- maybe others

Are there cases when inclusion of corresponding headers is mandatory?

Comment: Please don't incorporate content from answers into your question. It invalidates them, making for a confusing read and a poor repayment of other's effort

Comment: Is current correction make sense?

Comment: Better, I suppose. Not quite as a confusing read anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, not all of your examples behave as you seem to expect. For instance

> **[expr.typeid]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.typeid#6) If the header `<typeinfo>` is not included prior to a use of
>   `typeid`, the program is ill-formed.
>
> **[dcl.init.list]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#2) ... The template `std​::​initializer_­list` is not predefined; if
>   the header `<initializer_­list>` is not included prior to a use of
>   `std​::​initializer_­list` — even an implicit use in which the type is
>   not named — the program is ill-formed.

So there's two examples right off the bat. And sure, you can get by without including *some* headers, for instance

```
using size_t    = decltype(sizeof(0));
using nullptr_t = decltype(nullptr);
```

But in general, the way to guarantee with complete certainty that we get well-defined results, is to include the proper header for standard types.

Comment: You [right](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KjMGArJJeytceVjU). Some time ago it seems to me I was able to compile this code using either gcc or clang. But maybe I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there cases when inclusion of corresponding headers is mandatory?

I am not a language lawyer, and C++11 is too difficult to master for me (see [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)), but on implementations like [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) a standard header can and often does contain compiler specific tricks like `#pragma`s, [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), or [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).
Today at end of 2019, GCC uses such tricks for at least `<cstdarg>` and actually in many other cases (try `grep -rn __attribute__ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/` on a recent Debian, for instance).

My understanding is that a standard header might not even exist as a file on your system. It could be magic inside the compiler, processing `#include <map>` specifically to change the compiler's state. However, I know no compiler doing that in 2019. According to rumors, [VisualAge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualAge) did that in the previous century.

So I believe that the inclusion of standard headers is required, when you use them.